# How to pass object to function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Learning type script--
emp object is created at the end, but need to pass it inputData function to print the form data.

class empdata {
public empid : number;   public empname : string;   public job :    string;   public leaves: number;

```
   constructor (empid : number, empname : string, job : string, leaves    : number){
     this.empid = empid;    this.empName= empName;    this.job=job;    this.leaves=leaves;   }
 
     inputData(){
 
   console.log(this.empname);
   console.log(this.job);
   console.log(this.leaves);
 
   }
    getFormData (){
     const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('#myform')!;
 
   form.onsubmit = () => {
   const formData = new FormData(form);
   const empName = formData.get('emp') as string;
   const job = formData.get('job') as string;
   const leaves = formData.get('leaves') as string;
   
   return false; // prevent reload    };    } } let emp = new empdata(1,"srikanth","manager",10); emp.getFormData();
```

emp.inputData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a function but did not call it. You can keep your definition in class (Not specifically in the constructor), and you can call it after your object creation like:

```js
constructor(...)
{
  this.inputData();
}

inputData()
{
   console.log(this.empname);
   console.log(this.job);
   console.log(this.leaves);
}

//After your object creation
this.inputData(); // call again
```

UPDATE:
From the comment, if you wish to update the values during object creation and during formdata value changes, you can make use of the same function inputData() to achieve this:

```js
constructor(){
  this.empid = empid;
  this.inputData(empName, job, leaves);
}

inputData(empName, job, leaves){
  this.empName= empName;    
  this.job=job;    
  this.leaves=leaves; 
   
  console.log(this.empname);
  console.log(this.job);
  console.log(this.leaves);
}

// Afer updating form:
this.inputData(empName, job, leaves);
```

Comment: let emp = new empdata(1,"srikanth","manager",10);

is it necessary to pass data while creating object?

i want to pass the form data.

Comment: Why do you want to create a new object with form data as new values? You can simply update this.empname, this.job, and this.leaves values inside your inputData() function itself and then console.log them.